# Way to colorize SVG sprite

Tags: css, svg, sprite

## Help me with a way to colorize SVG sprite.

I already discovered we technics:

1. List item
2. CSS3 filters
3. CSS3 masks
4. Adding stroke and fill params `<use style="stroke:#96c16c" xlink:href="img/icons.svg#lightbulb"></use>`

I saw but don't remembered about `<filter>` tag method can you please give link to description of this method and any other method i missed...

Comment: You could use class or id attribute on SVG element and then change the `stroke` color via CSS.

Comment: But it dosen't override actual `stroke` or/and `fill` attributes. Overriding need for me because i use same icons as CSS background and as inline icons

Comment: You could leave the stroke attribute unset and color the element via stylesheet in svg's defs element, then recolor using other stylesheets with rules having higher specificity. The only other real option that doesn't require the svg to be dynamically generated server side would be a javascript function that alters the stroke attribute. Which probably won't be an option if the svg is being pulled in as an image via CSS instead of inserted into the actual DOM.